# Adding data elements from a model of like text to an array for a total non null count MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 I am trying to add all the elements of a model to an array so I can get a count of all the non-null values.

For example:
Model

```
public bool? Intubated_1 {get; set; }
public bool? Intubated_2 {get; set; }
public bool? Intubated_3 {get; set; }
public bool? Intubated_4 {get; set; }
public bool? Intubated_5 {get; set; }
public bool? some other fields
```

etc...

Is there a way to put all the Intubated_x values in an array to get the count of all the non-null values or do I have to put all 32 values in statement and check and add to an array individually?

**EDIT:**
Many thanks to all the solutions.  I took pieces and modified a bit to fit what I was looking for.  I have other bools so I can just go through all bools so the key was the .Name.StartsWith that was suggested.

```
List<bool?> intubatedList = new List<bool?>();
foreach (var p in adm.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (p.Name.StartsWith("Intubated") && p.GetValue(adm) != null)
       intubatedList.Add((bool?)p.GetValue(adm));
}
if (intubatedList.Count == adm.LOS)
    return true;
```

Comment: Is this your ViewModel, or some entity in your database?

Comment: Dude, any feedback so far? Looks like you already have the answer you need.

Comment: @Johnny5 This is in my Entity in the database.

Comment: @AndreCalil I am trying the options below now.  I had to step away for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is through reflection. With the following function you enumerate all the properties, get their values and add them to a List:

```
List<bool?> myList = new List<bool?>();
foreach (var p in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    mylist.Add((bool?)p.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```

Of course, if you have other properties in your class, before adding it to the array you'd need to check whether it's one of the properties you want to check (for example `p.Name.StartsWith("Intubated")`)

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
    public bool? Intubated_1 {get; set; }
    public bool? Intubated_2 {get; set; }
    public bool? Intubated_3 {get; set; }
    public bool? Intubated_4 {get; set; }
    public bool? Intubated_5 {get; set; }

    public List<bool?> NullableBoolPropertiesList()
    {
        List<bool?> properties = new List<bool?>();

        Type type = this.GetType();

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
            {
                bool? value = property.GetValue(this) as bool?;

                properties.Add(value);
            }
        }

        return properties;
    }
```

Usage:

```
        List<bool?> nullableBools = yourObject.NullableBoolPropertiesList();

        int howManyAreSet = nullableBools.Where(x => x.HasValue).Count();
        int howManyAreTrue = nullableBools.Where(x => x.HasValue && x.Value).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something a little slicker:

```
private readonly bool?[] _boolArray = new bool?[5];

// Your properties
public bool? Intubated_1
{
    get
    {
        return _boolArray[0];
    }
    set
    {
        _boolArray[0] = value;
    }
}

public bool? Intubated_2
{
    get
    {
        return _boolArray[1];
    }
    set
    {
        _boolArray[1] = value;
    }
}


// Count
public int CountNonNull
{
    get
    {
        return _boolArray.Count(i => i != null);
    }
}
```